# How to point textmate to the same version of python I get at the command line

Tags: python, macos, textmate

My Textmate uses python 2.6.1 and my system uses 2.6.5. This is not a big deal for the difference between them in terms of functionality, but all the packages that I installed with easy_install are not available to the Textmate version (2.6.1), though they are available to 2.6.5.

After researching this question I typed `which python` at the command line and learned that the desired python is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python`.

I tried alternately adding a `TM_PYTHON` to the shell variables or a `#!` pointing to the path above.  The result of each is the error msg `IndexError: list index out of range`, passed by module Q = sys.argv[1].

I cleared these out and tried creating a `/usr/.profile` with the line

```
alias python='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python'
```

with no effect.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your question properly (I did this for you this time as you are new). There is help available on the right side of the page when editing a question (or an answer). Making your question **readable and understandable** dramatically increases the chances that anybody will dedicate some of *their* time to help on *your* problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there.

In the *menubar*, click *TextMate*, then select *Preferences* from the drop-down menu, and then click *Advanced* from among the options at the top of the pop-up window. Next, click *Shell Variables* from among the three items near the top of the Advanced pane.

```
menubar > TextMate > Preferences > Advanced > Shell Variables
```

Here, you want to add *two* variable-value pairs, one for **PATH** and one for **PYTHONPATH**, so at the bottom left, click the "+" to add the first of these Variable-Value pair. You can edit either Variable or Value field by clicking in the text area.

The Value you want for **PATH** is the:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin
```

make sure this is the *first* directory that appears in the Value field for the PATH variable. If you want to add other directory paths to that Value field, separate it from the one you just added using a colon ":"

Next, create the variable **PYTHONPATH** and for the value, specify the directory that holds your *site packages*. It is probably this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

but definitely verify this.

When you have added these two variable, make sure that you *check the boxes* for each in the far left column.

(You might need to re-start TextMate.)

Finally, make sure your *hash bang* line at the top of your python script template is consistent with what you just did--i.e., the directory set for the value in PATH should simlink to the path specified in your pound bang line. The path specified in your pound hash bang should be a symlink to the python executable.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to add the line below at the beginning of your script file:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python
```

The lion above is the result of:

```
which python
```